# Could be this picture be interpreteded as a pareto set?

Tags: macroeconomics, consumer-theory

[image]

Hi, is there a way to interpret this picture as a Pareto set? What assumptions are necessary for such an interpretation?

Comment: Not with monotone preferences.

Comment: Hi Michael, could you tell me why with monotone preferences there's no a pareto set? and to be honest I don't know how to interprete this picture as a "normal" edgeworth box. Could you help me with that?

Comment: who are the persons depicted on the picture?